navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition not working on localhost with Firefox, but it does on Chrome
I have a SUPER simple script that I am testing locally (127.0.0.1):
window.addEventListener('load',()=>{
    if("geolocation" in navigator){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, failureFunction, null);
    } else {
        console.log("Error");
    }
});

successFunction(successObject){
    console.log(successObject);
}

failureFunction(failureObject){
    console.log(failureObject);
}

When I execute this in Chrome, the successFunction gets hit and the GeolocationPosition object gets printed to the console.
However, if I try this with Firefox 128.5.0esr (64-bit) on Debian 12, the failureFunction gets hit and the GeolocationPositionError gets printed to the console with this:
GeolocationPositionError {
    code: 2,
    message: "Unknown error acquiring position"
}

With code: 2 being "POSITION_UNAVAILABLE"
This seems to be a recent development with Firefox, as I haven't had issues with this not too long ago.
I have given "Access your location" permission in Firefox, and I have no issues with this on sites on the open internet.

I would try latest Firefox, and even developer version of firefox - it may be a "fixed" issue - i.e. works fine in 133 (release) and 134(dev) for me - note, the code you posted is not valid

@Bravo I thought about that, but I have no option to update; meaning it is at it's latest version available.

Is the lack of update a constraint enforced by a workplace or something? Does location work with external websites?

@Bravo It's not a workplace thing, it's right here on my personal computer. And, yes, location works great on all external websites ... even ones I have on my hosting provider.

so, why can't you install the developer version or release version of firefox (they can co-exist with the ESR version)

@Bravo I can, and I'll do that now. Thanks.
